# With Chart.js, can I align a div that's outside the canvas to the axes?

Tags: javascript, html, css, chart.js

Chart.js renders its axes in a canvas. Below that canvas, I have a div containing a control (in this case an input slider).

I want to add a margin to the div (or otherwise manipulate it), so that the div itself (and therefore the control within it) is aligned not to the canvas but to the axes within (i.e. so the slider pictured below is the same width as the axes).

Is it possible to do this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

## Answer For Chart.js Canvas

- Extending the below example for a chart.js canvas
- You can set the width of the y axis (50px in my example)

```
    options: {
        scales: {
            y: {
                afterFit: function (scaleInstance) {
                    scaleInstance.width = 50; // sets the width to 50px
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

- Use this known value to set the width of the graph using the slider input

```
const sliderToPercentageWidth = (sliderVal) => {
    return (50 + (containerWidth - 50) * (sliderVal/100) )
};
```

- You can also keep track of the `containerWidth` on window resize using

```
window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
});
```

This all comes together to give the code below [(also on CodePen)](https://codepen.io/papapps/pen/PoxyVxe):

### HTML

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="graph">
        <canvas id="myChart"></canvas>
    </div>
    <input id="width-selector" type="range" value="50">
    
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#container{
    background-color: #ff000020;
    width: 80vw;
    height:90vh;
}

#graph{
    height: 70vh;
    width: 40vw;
    background-color: #00ff0020;
}

#width-selector{
    width: calc(100% - 50px);
    margin-left: 50px;
}
```

### JS

```
const sliderToPercentageWidth = (sliderVal) => {
    return (50 + (containerWidth - 50) * (sliderVal/100) )
};

const rangeInput = document.getElementById("width-selector");
const graph = document.getElementById("graph");
const container = document.getElementById("container");
let containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;

// Match the slider width to graph on first render
const newWidth = sliderToPercentageWidth(rangeInput.value)
graph.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;

window.addEventListener("resize", (event) => {
    containerWidth = container.offsetWidth;
});

rangeInput.oninput = () => {
    const newWidth = sliderToPercentageWidth(rangeInput.value)
    graph.style.width = `${newWidth}px`;
};


// A basic chart
// Option for y axis width set

const ctx = document.getElementById("myChart");

new Chart(ctx, {
    type: "bar",
    data: {
        labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
        datasets: [
            {
                label: "# of Votes",
                data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
                borderWidth: 1
            }
        ]
    },
    options: {
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        scales: {
            y: {
                afterFit: function (scaleInstance) {
                    scaleInstance.width = 50; // sets the width to 50px
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

### Old Incorrect Answer

You can use JS to track the value of the input slider and when it changes set the CSS styling of the graph.

Here is a quick example to get you started as I cannot see the exact code you are working with.

It has very basic HTML, CSS but uses the input value (the slider) to set the width of the "graph" div using `.style.width`.

```
<div class="container">
    <div id="graph"></div>
    <input id="width-selector" type="range" value="50">
</div>
```

```
.container{
    background-color: red;
    width: 50vw;
    height:70vh;
}

#graph{
    height: 50vh;
    /*  Set the default width to match the input slider value */
    width: 50%; 
    background-color:blue;
}

#width-selector{
    width: 100%;
}
```

```
const rangeInput = document.getElementById("width-selector");

const graph = document.getElementById("graph")

rangeInput.oninput = () => {
    graph.style.width = `${rangeInput.value}%`
}
```

If your current document is different to my example set up please share your code with us & I will look to update my example.

Comment: I appreciate the time to make the answer @p7dxb. This correctly shows how to set widths of html elements. However, the question refers to the chart.js canvas, into which axes are painted. So the question requires getting the coordinates of something that's painted inside a canvas, not getting the dimension of the canvas HTML element itself.

Comment: @thclark. Sorry for the incorrect answer. I believe the new code answers the question.
Thank you for the constructive feedback as well, looking back your question is clear about the canvas position so sorry for the first answer. Hope the new code is closer to what you are after.

Comment: Hi @thclark, I do believe I have understood the question in my answer. 
It uses a function with the chart.js `options: { scales: { y: { afterFit: } } }` to let you know the "x" location of the chart's y axis on the chart.js canvas. The other HTML widths are set to match this setting on the canvas.
In your comment you say "because it renders into a canvas and the HTML has no way of knowing what's inside that canvas and where" but the set options in my example let you know the y axis is 50px from the left edge of the canvas.

Comment: I'm very sorry. I think the link I used took me to your old answer which I saw hadn't changed - yes, I do believe the edited answer has great potential. Next time I'm working on this project (later this week) I'll give it a try, thank you so much for your efforts! (deleted my erroneous previous comment) :)

Comment: Not a problem. Fingers crossed this solution works for you when you try it 